# Apache 2.4 Basic Auth and allowed IP on a file

Tags: apache-2.4, ip, authentication, password

I'm trying to secure a file in Apache 2.4. It may be accessible from a set of IP addresses, and if not, ask a password to the user.

```
<Files index.php>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Administration"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    
    <RequireAny>
          Require ip 123.456.789.1
          Require ip 192.168.0.201
          Require ip abcd:def:dead:beef::/64
          Require valid-user
    </RequireAny>
</Files>
```

I can see the file if I'm from one of the IP addresses, but if not, no password is asked. I get a 401 error instead.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: I tested your configuration and it does work. What's in the error.log?

Comment: The "401 error" is how the server asks for a password.